# Run script with elevated right on windows 8.1 before logon

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, admin-rights

How can I run a powershell script with elevated permissions in windows 8.1 BEFORE any user logs on? I want it to execute at startup.

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on context, you would either make it a system service (using Microsoft's `srvany` or a third-party alternative like `nssm`) or use group policy to run it as a startup script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to review the use of a [Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783469(v=ws.10).aspx) script.

Answer (score 0):

The above was useful, the solution to this was quite simple after all.

In windows 8.1 go to "Run" > gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).

It can also run PowerShell scripts.